# How to write a script to verify changes in a long text file?

Tags: bash

I am programming a script to verify if some changes are right in a long `.txt` file. The idea is to find the new changes and compare these values with the old ones, I can see what are the parameters that were changed since the text file has the following structure per line:

```
TR_Partner=google
TR_New_Partner=google#
```

Every time that there is a change, the first line is the original value and the following line contains the same name, just with the added word "**New**" and the new value (in this case it is google#). I need to make a script that can check all the lines in a long text file in order to check if all the new values match with the original values, I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash


partner="$(grep -m1 Partner test.txt | cut -d"=" -f2)"
new_partner="$(grep -m1 New_Partner test.txt | cut -d"=" -f2)"

Data="$(grep -m1 Data test.txt | cut -d"=" -f2)"
New_Data="$(grep -m1 New_Data test.txt | cut -d"=" -f2)"

Direction="$(grep -m1 Direction test.txt | cut -d"=" -f2)"
New_Direction="$(grep -m1 New_Direction test.txt | cut -d"=" -f2)"


if [ $partner != $new_partner ]; then
    echo "warning invalid data"
    exit 1;
fi
if [ $Data != $New_Data ]; then
    echo "warning invalid data"
    exit 1;
fi
if [ $Direction != $New_Direction ]; then
    echo "warning invalid data"
    exit 1;
fi
```

I tested the code like this: `bash script.sh test.txt` and the desired output is this, since google doesn't match with google# :

```
warning invalid data
```

but this is a very bad approach since it doesn't work in general, I need to find a way to automatize this task, I would like to appreciate any suggestion or hint of how to proceed with this difficult task.

The the `file.txt` is this :

```
 ENTERPRISE
 AB_EDI_Number=number
 AB_Partner=google
 AB_New_Partner=google#    
 AB_Data_Type=null
 AB_New_Data_Type=null
 AB_Address=address 
 AB_New_Address=address
```

Comment: Use `diff` That is what it is for and not much point in trying to recreate it...Or put your file in a version control system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this.

```sh
last_key=""
last_value=""
# read line by line
while read -r line; do
    # split at = into pairs
    IFS="=" read -r key value <<< "$line"
    # Check if key contains "New" and the value from the line before is
    # different from the value in the current line. Note: uses bash
    # extended test ([[]]), use grep for posix shell.
    if [[ "$key" == *New* ]] && [ "$last_value" != "$value" ]; then
        echo "warning: $last_value != $value"
        exit 1 # omit if you want to find all differences
    fi
    # save value, key for the next iteration
    last_key="$key"
    last_value="$value"
done < "$1"
```

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciated your help with this difficult task, this was very useful.

Answer (score 1):

This will show field names that have changed values:

```
sed 's/_New_/_/' file.txt | uniq | sed 's/=.*//' | uniq -d
```

Example (considering only input lines 3-6 for brevity):

1st sed

```
TR_Partner=google
TR_New_Partner=google#
TR_Data_Type=null
TR_New_Data_Type=null
```

->

```
TR_Partner=google
TR_Partner=google#
TR_Data_Type=null
TR_Data_Type=null
```

1st uniq: remove adjacent duplicate lines (fields with unchanged values)

```
TR_Partner=google
TR_Partner=google#
TR_Data_Type=null
TR_Data_Type=null
```

->

```
TR_Partner=google
TR_Partner=google#
TR_Data_Type=null
```

2nd sed: delete the "=" and everything following

```
TR_Partner=google
TR_Partner=google#
TR_Data_Type=null
```

->

```
TR_Partner
TR_Partner
TR_Data_Type
```

2nd uniq: show duplicate lines (fields with changed values)

```
TR_Partner
```